# Password Strength Checker

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a problem with my Password Strength checker.
Color of the result doesn't change according to the strength of the password.
I guess i have problem with "addClass" in javascript.
Here is the code...

html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />     
     <script src="script.js"></script>      
   </head>

    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">  
            <form name="pass_strength">
            <p><label for="username">Username : </label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="input"/>
            </p>
            <p><label for="password">Password : </label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input" />
                <span id="result"></span> 
           </p>
            </form>     
        </div>

       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
      body
      { background-color:#CCC;}

    #container
     {
    width:20%;  
    background-color:#000;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:5px solid #FFF;
   margin-top:150px;
   }
   #content
   {
     padding:10px;
     border: 2px solid rgb(105, 91, 91);
     box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #FFF;
     background: #CCC;
    }
 .input
 {
  margin:10px;
 }


 #result
 {
    color:#F00;
    text-shadow:#666;
 }

 a
 {
    color:#000;
 }

.red{color:red;}
.orange{color:orange;}
.green{color:green;}
```

JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#password').keyup(function(){
    $('#result').html(checkStrength($('#password').val()))
  })    

  function checkStrength(password){

  var strength = 0

  if (password.length < 6) { 
    $('#result').removeClass()
    $('#result').addClass('short green')
    return 'Too short' 
   }

  if (password.length > 7) strength += 1

  if (password.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/))  strength += 1

  if (password.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && password.match(/([0-9])/))  strength += 1 

  if (password.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/))  strength += 1

  if (password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~].*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength += 1


if (strength < 2 ) {
    $('#result').removeClass()
    $('#result').addClass('weak')
    $('#result').addClass('green')
    return 'Weak'           
} else if (strength == 2 ) {
    $('#result').removeClass('green')
    $('#result').addClass('orange')
    return 'Good'       
} else {
    $('#result').removeClass('red')
    $('#result').removeClass('orange')
    $('#result').addClass('strong','green')
    return 'Strong'
}
}
});
```

Comment: " have a problem with my Password Strength checker. "  - This isn't an issue with your CSS, and most likely not your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have provided color to id of span element.Id attribute has an highest priority than class attribute so the color is not assigned to the result.

You can add class to the `<span>` element and give color to that class.

You can see demo here http://jsfiddle.net/tenigada/RH8f6/575/

Answer (score 1):

i have found  [this](https://jsfiddle.net/umesh1990/hxjf74cz/35/#) it may help you i have implement using javascript

```js
function password_validate(txt) {
  var val1 = 0;
  var val2 = 0;
  var val3 = 0;
  var val4 = 0;
  var val5 = 0;
  var counter, color, result;
  var flag = false;
  if (txt.value.length <= 0) {
    counter = 0;
    color = "transparent";
    result = "";
  }
  if (txt.value.length < 8 & txt.value.length > 0) {
    counter = 20;
    color = "red";
    result = "Short";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(txt.id + "error").innerHTML = " ";
    txt.style.borderColor = "grey";
    var regex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{8,15}$/;
    //  document.getElementById("pass_veri").style.display="block";
    var fletter = /[a-z]/;
    if (fletter.test(txt.value)) {
      val1 = 20;

    } else {
      val1 = 0;
    }
    //macth special character
    var special_char = /[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/;
    if (special_char.test(txt.value)) {
      val2 = 30;
    } else {
      val = 0;
    }
    /*capital_letter*/
    var cap_lett = /[A-Z]/;
    if (cap_lett.test(txt.value)) {
      val3 = 20;
    } else {
      val = 0;
    }
    /*one numeric*/
    var num = /[0-9]/;
    if (num.test(txt.value)) {
      val4 = 20;
    } else {
      val4 = 0;
    }
    /* 8-15 character*/
    var range = /^.{8,50}$/;
    if (range.test(txt.value)) {
      val5 = 10;
    } else {
      val5 = 0;
    }
    counter = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5;

    if (counter >= 30) {
      color = "skyblue";
      result = "Fair";
    }
    if (counter >= 50) {
      color = "gold";
      result = "Good";
    }
    if (counter >= 80) {
      color = "green";
      result = "Strong";
    }
    if (counter >= 90) {
      color = "green";
      result = "Very Strong";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("prog").style.width = counter + "%";
  document.getElementById("prog").style.backgroundColor = color;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  document.getElementById("result").style.color = color;
}
```

```css
  body {
    font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif;
    background-color: #E4E4E4;
  }
  /* tooltip*/
  
  .hint {
    width: 258px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #CC9933;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  
  .hint:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 24px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 17px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-left: 22px solid #CC9933;
  }
  
  .hint:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 26px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 14px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #FFFFCC;
  }
  
  .parent {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .progress {
    height: 7px;
  }
  
  #progres {
    display: block;
  }
  
  p {
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  .form-control {
    width: none;
    margin-left: 260px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group col-lg-12 parent ">
  <label class="hint" id="pass-hint">
    Password Strength:<span id="result"></span>
    <br>
    <div class="progress" id="progres">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" id="prog">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p> passowrd must have atleast 8 charatcer</p>
  </label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" id="pass" onfocus="document.getElementById('pass-hint').style.display='block'" onblur="document.getElementById('pass-hint').style.display='none'" placeholder="**********"
  oninput="password_validate(this);document.getElementById('progres').style.display='block';">
  <i class=" form-control-feedback" id="passsuccess" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span id="passerror" class="help-block error"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Used to this

```
 #result.red{color:red;}
 #result.orange{color:orange;}
 #result.green{color:green;}
```

Because you used to `ID` and than apply to class css but `id` is more power than `class` than used to with `ID` and class this `css`.

Demo code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#password').keyup(function(){
    $('#result').html(checkStrength($('#password').val()))
  })    

  function checkStrength(password){

  var strength = 0

  if (password.length < 6) { 
    $('#result').removeClass()
    $('#result').addClass('short green')
    return 'Too short' 
   }

  if (password.length > 7) strength += 1

  if (password.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/))  strength += 1

  if (password.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && password.match(/([0-9])/))  strength += 1 

  if (password.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/))  strength += 1

  if (password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~].*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength += 1


if (strength < 2 ) {
    $('#result').removeClass()
    $('#result').addClass('weak');
    $('#result').addClass('green');
    return 'Weak'           
} else if (strength == 2 ) {
    $('#result').removeClass('green');
    $('#result').addClass('orange');
    return 'Good'       
} else {
    $('#result').removeClass('red');
    $('#result').removeClass('orange');
    $('#result').addClass('strong green');
    return 'Strong'
}
}
});
```

```css
  body
      { background-color:#CCC;}

    #container
     {
    width:20%;  
    background-color:#000;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:5px solid #FFF;
   margin-top:150px;
   }
   #content
   {
     padding:10px;
     border: 2px solid rgb(105, 91, 91);
     box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #FFF;
     background: #CCC;
    }
 .input
 {
  margin:10px;
 }


 #result
 {
    color:#F00;
    text-shadow:#666;
 }

 a
 {
    color:#000;
 }

 #result.red{color:red;}
 #result.orange{color:orange;}
 #result.green{color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />     
     <script src="script.js"></script>      
   </head>

    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">  
            <form name="pass_strength">
            <p><label for="username">Username : </label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="input"/>
            </p>
            <p><label for="password">Password : </label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input" />
                <span id="result"></span> 
           </p>
            </form>     
        </div>

       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```